# pactl load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc Failure: Module initialization failed

Tags: qt, pulseaudio, echo-cancellation

I'm working on an embedded linux device which has mic and should communicate with another device using webrtc and running on a Qt QML application. during the call I have an echo that should be cancelled. I searched on the internet and I found that pulseaudio have a module for echo cancelling.

I tried adding `load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc` to /etc/pulse/default.pa but then pulseaudio won't even start.
when I try to use the command  pactl load-module module-echo-cancel to load it also fails saying that Failure: Module initialization failed
sadly I have no idea what this error is saying and googling it gave no usefull information...

so anyone have an idea what is the problem ?
I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and pulseaudio 8.0

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the echo was not removed does not necessarily mean that the echo module is not running. Unfortunately, there are cases, especially on embedded devices, that cause some echo cancellation software not to function correctly. In the following post you can read about the complexity and challenges of [echo cancellation software](https://solicall.com/echo-cancellation-art-or-science-part-v/). Assuming this is the case, you should try running a different AEC module or debug your existing webRTC module.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. I found that the echo cancellation is running using `pactl list sources|sinks` command but I still have echo during the call. I tried changing aec modules but no changes.